# How to use PHP to create hundreds of dynamic pages with distinct MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, scripting

I have a simple MySQL table below and am currently displaying the contents of it with the code at the bottom of this post.

For sake of demonstration I only included 3 records here but in reality I have hundreds of records and would like to find some way of generating hundreds of pages dynamically, where each page displays a distinct row from the database.

For example:

```
page1.php -(contents)- Jonathan Smith
page2.php -(contents)- Samantha Rafael
page3.php -(contents)- Robert Weadababitzaboi
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

members table

id  firstName lastName
1 Jonathan Smith
2 Samantha Rafael
3 Robert Weadababitzaboi

```
<?php  

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members;
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo displayResults($result);
$db->close();

function displayResults($result) {
//build it
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $r .= '<div id="firstName"><img src="';
            $r .=  htmlspecialchars($row->firstName) ;
    $r .= '"></div>';
            $r .= '<div id="lastName">';
            $r .=  htmlspecialchars($row->lastName) ;
    $r .= '</div>';
}
return $r;
}
```

Comment: There's a quote missing after SELECT * FROM members

Comment: Why would you want a separate page for each when you could have one piece of code and link to it domain.com/mem/1 domain.com/mem/2 etc

Comment: What would you like the url for a particular page to look like?

Comment: You mean you want one page to be used dynamically to get each users page, and as blamonet said below you could use htaccess to mod_reqrite the urls

Answer (score 0):

You could use .htaccess (if you are using Apache) and do some rewrites that can be seen on this page: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/More_.htaccess_mod_rewrite_examples

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create files, this is what you need: `http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the member's ID in as a GET parameter to your URL:

`domain.example.org/member.php?id=42`

Prepare a statement to retrieve that one member's details from the DB:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
```

And render your page using the result.

The chances are you don't need to do anything more complex than that.

Comment: How does the script know which `id` to look for though? I understand that the second code your wrote above will get the information for a particular id, but how does it know to look for `id=42` even though it is on that page?

Comment: @McLean25 the ID is being passed in as part of the URL linked to from the previous page. In the question you can see the asker has an index page where he is listing each of the items from his DB table.

Comment: Does PHP recognize the id from the url? Or from a global variable being passed? All that he has to do to set the url is `<a href=domain.example.org/member.php?id='.$id.'></a>` Correct?

Comment: Also, where is `$this` coming from?